# How to have a follower count on django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I have been working on a follow system like in instagram in which a user can follow and unfollow other users, also a profile has to display the number of followers the selected user has and the number of people that user is following. Everything is working fine except for the followers count which is not displaying any number rather than 0 which is the default even tho the user has one or more followers. How can a count function be added to this django project?

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', null=True, blank=True, default='default.png')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=400, default=1, null=True)
    connection = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True)
    follower = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    following = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

class Following(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    followed = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="followed")
    follower = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="follower")

    @classmethod
    def follow(cls, user, another_account):
        obj, create = cls.objects.get_or_create(user = user)
        obj.followed.add(another_account)
        print("followed")

    @classmethod
    def unfollow(cls, user, another_account):
        obj, create = cls.objects.get_or_create(user = user)
        obj.followed.remove(another_account)
        print("unfollowed")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

views.py

```
def profile(request, username=None):
    profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    user = User.objects.filter(username=username)
    if user:
        post_owner = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
        profile_bio = Profile.objects.filter(user_id=post_owner)
        user_posts = Post.objects.filter(user_id=post_owner)
        user = user[0]
        is_following = Following.objects.filter(user=request.user, followed=user)
        following_obj = Following.objects.get(user=user)
        follower = following_obj.follower.count()
        following = following_obj.followed.count()

    else:
        post_owner = request.user
        user_posts = Post.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        profile_bio = Profile.objetcs.filter(user=request.user)
        
    args1 = {
        'user_obj':user,
        'post_owner': post_owner,
        'user_posts': user_posts,
        'follower': follower,
        'following': following,
        'connection': is_following,
        'profile_bio': profile_bio,
    }
    return render(request, 'profile.html', args1)

def follow(request, username):
    main_user = request.user
    to_follow = User.objects.get(username=username)
    following = Following.objects.filter(user = main_user, followed = to_follow)
    is_following = True if following else False 
    if is_following:
        Following.unfollow(main_user, to_follow)
        is_following = False
    else:
        Following.follow(main_user, to_follow)
        is_following = True
    resp = {
        'following': is_following,
    }
    response = json.dumps(resp)
    return HttpResponse(response, content_type="application/json")
```

profile.html

```
<div class="header-item">
  {{ follower }}
</div>
<div class="header-item">
  {{ following }}
</div>

{% if connection %}
  <a type="button" class="button-caballo" id="follow" role="button" href="{% url 'follow' user_obj.username %}">Unfollow</a>
{% elif not connection %}
  <a type="button" class="button-caballo" id="follow" role="button" href="{% url 'follow' user_obj.username %}">Follow</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I don't get your relationship model of integers and double M2M relations. This should be a single M2M relation, maybe with an intermediate model if you need metadata on the relation.

Comment: @KlausD. What you suggest adding a new model? What should it have?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change follow function like this :

```
def follow(request, username):

    main_user = request.user
    to_follow = User.objects.get(username=username)
    following = Following.objects.filter(user = main_user, followed = to_follow).first()
 
    if following is not None:
        Following.unfollow(main_user, to_follow)
        is_following = False
        main_user.following -= 1
        to_follow.follower -= 1
    else:
        Following.follow(main_user, to_follow)
        is_following = True
        main_user.following += 1
        to_follow.follower += 1

    main_user.save()
    to_follow.save()

    resp = {
        'following': is_following,
    }
    response = json.dumps(resp)
    return HttpResponse(response, content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: Hey Parth! the code is still not showing the number of followers a user has, what can I do now?

Comment: @JuanMartinZabala Please check updated code snippet It may be works for you.

Comment: I am getting this errors  `File "C:\Users\USER\startup\gstartup\accounts\views.py", line 112, in follow
    main_user.following -= 1`  `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Following' and 'int'` How can these be fixed?

Comment: First you have to get object of main_user. Check updated code.